# Is there any connection between Stranger Things and IT movie?

Tags: reference, stranger-things, it-2017

Are [*Stranger Things*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_Things) and [*IT*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_(2017_film)) in the same universe?

In season 2 episode 3 of *Stranger Things* while Bob drives Will to school, Bob tells Will about a terrifying experience he had as a kid where a clown tried to give him a balloon by saying something like "Do you want a balloon?".

As *Stranger Things* is set in the 1980s, Bob would have been a child back in the 1950s, when the original novel of *IT* is set. And later Bob tells that his parents are from Maine, where *IT* took place.

Finn Wolfhard appear in Both *Stranger Things* and *IT*, playing the roles of Mike and Richie respectively. And he saying same dialogue in both, [LINK](https://twitter.com/UpsideDownFacts/status/924524049883045888)

Comment: People who find clowns frightening is not unique to, nor was it invented by the book or movie It.  A very common phobia/feeling/opinion.  Serial killer John Wayne Gacy was a clown as one of his jobs, and was famous for it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Is there any connection between Stranger Things and IT movie?**

Yes, IT is one of the inspirations behind the show.

From [huffingtonpost](http://www.huffingtonpost.in/entry/the-truth-behind-the-creepy-connection-between-it-and-stranger-things_us_5a00b54ee4b0baea2633f87b)

> The Duffer brothers, who actually once pitched an “It” remake themselves, recently told Vulture that the connections are completely intentional. But there seems to be one big hole in the theory.
>
> “Stranger Things” co-creator Matt Duffer first told Vulture that he
>   had a problem with the 1990 “It” miniseries as a kid, and Bob’s story
>   was inspired by that.
>
> “I think [Bob’s clown story] was really me describing something that
>   just freaked me out. I didn’t have that experience myself. I just had
>   nightmares like that,” he said.
>
> Duffer continued:
>
> > “I’m sure we were just like, ‘It would be cute if [Bob] suggests moving to Maine, right next to Stephen King.’ Stephen King exists in
> >     this world. Some of the characters have read Stephen King. But Bob
> >     definitely does not read Stephen King. He’s not interested at all in
> >     Stephen King because he hates that kind of story.”

**Is Stranger Things and IT is in the same universe?**

No, Stranger Things is inspired from so many 80s famous things, it's not canon to them but pays homage to them.

Even Finn Wolfhard play different roles: Mike Wheeler in Stranger Things and Richie Tozier in It (2017), saying same dialogue is more of easter-egg/reference only.

Even Mark Hamill said a Star Wars dialogue in Flash, still, Arrowverse is not canon to Star Wars

Related post: [Meaning of Mark Hamill's “I am your father” line from The Flash](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47172/meaning-of-mark-hamills-i-am-your-father-line-from-the-flash)